# How specify managed network when using Firebase (Database, Storage ...) component

Tags: android, firebase, network-programming, aaos

In automotive, there are network capabilities for OEM managed network, that allow an app developper to limit the network used by the app, to only specific network that own such capabilities.

We have for example [NET_CAPABILITY_OEM_PRIVATE](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:packages/modules/Connectivity/framework/src/android/net/NetworkCapabilities.java;drc=ab8411385ff99952764147cb69c66a50f189e320;bpv=1;bpt=1;l=641?q=.addCapability&gsn=NET_CAPABILITY_OEM_PRIVATE&gs=KYTHE%3A%2F%2Fkythe%3A%2F%2Fandroid.googlesource.com%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject%2Fmain%2F%2Fmain%3Flang%3Djava%3Fpath%3Dandroid.net.NetworkCapabilities%23d7ff6118b97901db2cb7a827e56413efa86b273b9d6d6d2b55b55a1643a4c5a5) or [NET_CAPABILITY_OEM_PAID](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:packages/modules/Connectivity/framework/src/android/net/NetworkCapabilities.java;drc=ab8411385ff99952764147cb69c66a50f189e320;bpv=1;bpt=1;l=609?q=.addCapability&gsn=NET_CAPABILITY_OEM_PAID&gs=KYTHE%3A%2F%2Fkythe%3A%2F%2Fandroid.googlesource.com%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject%2Fmain%2F%2Fmain%3Flang%3Djava%3Fpath%3Dandroid.net.NetworkCapabilities%23197c81cdceff9e2a8b33ae64030d2f3f4e4809e34c077dc2329b829d97f9c17f)

I want to develop a service with firebase that will only use this network. (this network is connected to internet ofcourse)

How to use various Firebase SDK to force them using such net capability. We need to have access to the android.net.NetworkAccess I think we do not have.

Here is a Github issue about it : https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/5138